# Too many updates! [18.04]

Tags: updates, 18.04

Why are there so frequent updates on Ubuntu 18.04? Or is it possible that I have the developer's edition? If yes, then how to verify?

Answer (score 0):

With: `lsb_release -a` in Terminal.
You can check version you have. However I do not think there is a separate version for developers. There are updates normally about twice a week but can be more frequent if you have lots of application installed. If you think you those too often you can automate the update process to certain extent. You can go to Software and Updates application and select various updates which can be done without asking you in background.